# In D3js how can I give delay for updating each node

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using D3js. I made a Force-Directed Graph. But when I want to update each node color(my main goal is to do some calculation then base On the result change color) it happens at same time for all node. I want to have a delay when I finished one node then go to next one. Also I want to check all nodes regularly. so the function `colorChange` should be executed every 2 second.

this is the [main code](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045) for graph.

and this is my code for updating color in nodes:

```
d3.interval(colorChange, 2000);

function colorChange(){
  var color = d3.select("circle").style("fill");
  if (color == "rgb(0, 0, 255)")
    d3.selectAll("circle").each(function(){
      d3.select(this).style("fill","red");
    });
  else
    d3.selectAll("circle").style("fill","blue");

}
```

Comment: Delete the d3.interval ?

Comment: I want to check all nodes regularly. so the function `colorChange` should be executed every 2 second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question (I mean, the desired outcome) is not exactly clear, but I guess that you can get what you want using a transition with delay, instead of `each`:

```
function colorChange() {
    var color = d3.select("circle").style("fill");
    if (color == "rgb(0, 0, 255)") {
        d3.selectAll("circle")
            .transition()
            .delay((d, i) => i * 50)
            .duration(100)
            .style("fill", "red");

    } else {
        d3.selectAll("circle")
            .transition()
            .delay((d, i) => i * 50)
            .duration(100)
            .style("fill", "blue");
    }
}
```

Here is the updated code (I changed the interval to 5 secs, just to give time to paint all the circles, so please wait a little bit for the first call): https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/raw/bf1921449e33d89ba6259167231f5b32/

Comment: there is one other thing. where should I call my `checkStatus` function to see whether the node change or not, base on the result?

Comment: Well, as this was not clear in the question, I suggest you post *another* question, better explaining your problem. If you ask this here, in the comments, I'm the only one reading it. On the other hand, if you post a new question, everybody's gonna read it.

Comment: but I explained it already `update each node color(my main goal is to do some calculation then base On the result change color)`

Answer (score 0):

This might do what you are trying to achieve:

```
d3.interval(colorChange, 2000);

function colorChange(){
  var color = d3.select("circle").style("fill");
  if (color == "rgb(0, 0, 255)")
    d3.selectAll("circle").each(function(){
      d3.select(this).style("fill","red");
      // How long to wait in ms
      sleep(100);
    });
  else
    d3.selectAll("circle").style("fill","blue");

}

function sleep(ms) {
   var now = new Date().getTime();
   while(new Date().getTime() < now + ms){ /* do nothing */ } 
}
```

Comment: there is an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` in line `await sleep(100);`